# cordova 3.4 create custom plugin

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, record

I am trying to create my own Android plugin for Cordova 3.4.

The plugin must simply call the Android mediaRecorder, record from the mic for 7 seconds, create a file on the SD card and stop recording.

When I try and call the plugin from inside my Cordova / Ionic project I keep getting a "Class not found" error without further elaboration.

The Java looks as follows:

```
    package com.example.myplugin;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Environment;

public class Recorder extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        String outputFile = null;
        final MediaRecorder myRecorder;

        outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
                  getAbsolutePath() + "/TestRecording.m4a";

        myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        myRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
        myRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
        myRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(32000);
        myRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

        try 
        {
              myRecorder.prepare();
              myRecorder.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            callbackContext.error(e.getMessage());   
            return false;   
        }

        CountDownTimer countDowntimer = new CountDownTimer(7000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

        public void onFinish() {
            myRecorder.stop();
            myRecorder.release();           

            //Sets the callback type and sets the return to true to define successful.      
            callbackContext.success();
            //return true;
        }
        };

        countDowntimer.start();

        return true;

    }

    }
```

The JS looks as follows:

```
    var RecordAudio = {
    recordAudio: function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
        cordova.exec(
            successCallback, // success callback function
            errorCallback, // error callback function
            'Recorder', // mapped to our native Java class called "Recorder"
            'recordAudio', // with this action name
            []                  //Array of arguments to pass
        ); 
    }
};

    module.exports = RecordAudio;
```

The plugin XML is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<plugin xmlns="http://www.phonegap.com/ns/plugins/1.0"
           id="com.mytest.recorder"
      version="0.1.0">
  <name>Recorder</name>

  <description>Android Recorder plugin</description>        


    <js-module src="www/Recorder.js" name="Recorder">   
        <clobbers target="window.RecordAudio" />     
    </js-module>

    <!-- android -->
    <platform name="android">
        <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="Recorder">
                <param name="android-package" value="Recorder"/>
            </feature>
        </config-file>

        <source-file src="src/Recorder.java" target-dir="com/mytest/recorder/" />      
     </platform>          
</plugin>
```

calling it as follows:

```
var onSuccess = function(dataReturned){
      console.log(dataReturned);

    }

    var onFailure = function(dataReturned){
      console.log(dataReturned);

    }

    RecordAudio.recordAudio(onSuccess, onFailure);
```

Can anyone see what's wrong with the Java that would cause this error?

Many thanks for any feedback!!!

Answer (score 0):

have you added the Plugin to config.xml file ??

It should have something like this

```
<feature name="Recorder" >
        <param name="android-package" value="com.example.myplugin.Recorder " />
</feature>
```

If yes, please provide the stack trace for better information.

EDIT1: 
Just saw the plugin.xml.. i think it has been removed, coz i could only get my plugin working by putting the code in Config.xml